# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource

Tags: java, android

I have a consts class:

```
public class AppConstants {
    public static final class Projects {
        public static final String JOB = Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.job);
        // more...
    }
}
```

I want to use this consts in runtime:

```
if (AppConstants.Projects.JOB.equals(curr)) {
   // do stuff
}
```

But I get the following exception:

```
/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f1101cc
```

How should I fix it? I think it happens because I use the keyword `static`. But how than I can access those fields?

Answer (score 1):

JavaDoc of [`getSystem()`](http://getSystem%20()) says:

> Return a global shared Resources object that provides access to only system resources (no application resources), is not configured for the current screen (can not use dimension units, does not change based on orientation, etc), and is not affected by Runtime Resource Overlay.

Is R.string.job a *system* resource or an *application resource*?

JavaDoc also says:

> You can generally acquire the Resources instance associated with your application with [Context#getResources()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getResources()).

---

`R.string.job` is not a system resource, so you need to access it through `Context`. You can than call `context.getResources().getString(x)` or directly `context.getString(x)`.

so why don't you just use this? (assuming you are already in a context, like an Activity or Application)

```
if (getString(R.string.job).equals(curr)) {
   // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Did this help you? If yes, you could accept my answer